# How do I apply 2 different stylesheets to one React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a React component that has a className which imports a stylesheet to apply to it. Then, when the component is used I give it a className to style it again with a different stylesheet imported into the place it is used.

I've tried using IDs instead, no luck. I've looked through developer tools and the 2nd stylesheet is not applied to it at all.

This is Button.js

```
import '../styles/button.scss';

export default (props) => {
    return(
        <div className='button'>
            <button>{props.name}</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

button.scss

```
.button {
    button {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0.5em;
        font-family: inherit;
    }
}
```

Now when it's actually used

```
import '../styles/navbar.scss';
<Button name='Cart' className='navbar cartButton'/>
```

navbar.scss

```
.navbar {
    .cartButton {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

For example, the color red would not get applied

Answer (score 0):

`className` only really works like you expect on native html elements like a `<div>`.

To pass the className along you would need to do sth like:

```
export default (props) => {
    return(
        <div className={'button ' + props.className}>
            <button>{props.name}</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

after that you'd need to find the right css queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change scss to

```
.navbar {
    &.cartButton {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

or

```
.navbar.cartButton {
        color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, can't believe I forgot basic SASS syntax. However, none of these css properties don't actually apply on top of the previously applied ones from button.scss. Still a bit stuck!